# Не найдена несуществующая колонка PeeWee

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, peewee

Подключая библиотеку PeeWee к таблице я заметил, что не могу никак взаимодействовать с информацией находящейся в ней. Библиотека выдаёт ошибку о том, что она не нашла колонку с названием "tl.id". Я такой колонки не создавал. Ниже прикреплю фото таблицы, сам код и скрин ошибки.

```
from peewee import *

db_hw = SqliteDatabase("HOMEWORK.db")


class MONDAY(Model):
   Lesson = TextField()
   HW = TextField()

   class Meta:
      database = db_hw


for itm in MONDAY.select():
   print(itm)
```

**Код ошибки:**

```
C:\Users\arsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python373\python.exe C:/Users/arsen/PycharmProjects/Vk_Bot/file.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python373\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2940, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: t1.id

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/arsen/PycharmProjects/Vk_Bot/file.py", line 14, in <module>
    for itm in MONDAY.select():
  File "C:\Users\arsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python373\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 6435, in __iter__
    self.execute()
  File "C:\Users\arsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python373\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 1785, in inner
    return method(self, database, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\arsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python373\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 1856, in execute
    return self._execute(database)
  File "C:\Users\arsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python373\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2027, in _execute
    cursor = database.execute(self)
  File "C:\Users\arsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python373\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2953, in execute
    return self.execute_sql(sql, params, commit=commit)
  File "C:\Users\arsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python373\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2947, in execute_sql
    self.commit()
  File "C:\Users\arsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python373\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2729, in __exit__
    reraise(new_type, new_type(*exc_args), traceback)
  File "C:\Users\arsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python373\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 183, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\arsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python373\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2940, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
peewee.OperationalError: no such column: t1.id

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Фото таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решён тем, что я пересоздал таблицу через саму библиотеку PeeWee, используя метод "create_table()", а не через "DB Browser for SQLite".

Answer (score 0):

PeeWee нужно поле первичного ключа. В общем случае, рекомендую его сделать. По умолчанию это `id`.

Если оно точно не нужно, то:

```
class BaseModelView(peewee.Model):
    '''Базовая модель для представлений.'''
    class Meta:  # pylint: disable=C0111,R0903,R0903
        database = DB
        primary_key = False
```

Обрати внимание на строку: `primary_key = False`

Comment: Насколько я понял PeeWee нужно id-ми отмечать строки, а строка primary_key = False отключает эту необходимость?

Comment: В SQL есть понятие первичного ключа. Поле однозначно идентифицирующее одну запись. Обычно это поле `id` типа int с автоинкрементом. Иногда, например в представлениях, первичный ключ не используется. Часть функционала PeeWee связана с обращением к записи по первичному ключу, поэтому он автоматически ищет его в поле `id`. `primary_key = False` отключает использование первичного ключа. `create_table()` автоматически создает первичный ключ. https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/11/ddl-constraints#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS